# Writing and Plotting a Function of Another Function (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am entirely new to MATLAB and have been assigned a small project to plot some derivatives and trajectories. I am given:

f(t,x) = 0.02sin(2πt)(x^2 - 2x) + x;

dx/dt = -πsin(π*f(t,x))cos(πy);

dy/dt = πcos(πf(t,x))sin(πy)(∂f/∂x)

Existing code:

```
f = @(t,x,y) (0.02*sin(2*pi*t)*(x^2 - 2*x) + x);  
dfdx = @(t,x,y) (0.02*sin(2*pi*t)*(2*x - 2) + 1);
d = @(t,x,y) [-pi*sin(pi*f(t,x,y))*cos(pi*y); pi*cos(pi*f(t,x,y))*sin(pi*y)*dfdx(t,x,y)];

t = linspace(0,4,100);

figure
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:.1:2,0:0.1:1);
quiver(x,y,d(1),d(2));
```

I've tried to make this work on my own but given my unfamiliarity with the language I'm having a lot of difficulty. My goal (for the time being) is to plot dx/dt and dy/dt on a grid using the quiver function but I'm getting far too many errors before I get close to that point. Any suggestions on proper syntax to make this work?

Thanks!

I've tried rewriting the functions but have gotten a handful of errors; most commonly I've been told that "operation * does not work with function_handle," "not enough input arguments," and some others.

Comment: Please copy-paste your code into your question. That will make it easier to give you a useful answer.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have updated the post with existing code. I am well aware that it's very incorrect, but with my nonexistent experience with MATLAB it was all I could come up with. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

First, note the difference between the matrix product `*` and the element-wise multiplication `.*`. They are the same if the two operands are scalars (single values), but do very different things for matrix inputs. Since you are operating on matrix `t`, `x` and `y`, you should update your functions:

```matlab
f = @(t,x,y) (0.02*sin(2*pi*t).*(x.^2 - 2*x) + x);  
dfdx = @(t,x,y) (0.02*sin(2*pi*t).*(2*x - 2) + 1);
dxdt = @(t,x,y) -pi*sin(pi*f(t,x,y)).*cos(pi*y);
dydt = @(t,x,y) pi*cos(pi*f(t,x,y)).*sin(pi*y).*dfdx(t,x,y);
```

Every time both operands to `*` or `^` or `/` are vectors or matrices, you want to use the element-wise operator instead (`.*`, `.^`, `./`).

I've also separated out `dxdt` and `dydt`, because it is complicated to represent a vector output for a whole array of x and y values.

Next, when calling `d`, you must pass in the `t`, `x` and `y` you computed. Also, since we do not want to do 3D vector plots, we'll pick a single `t`, not an array of them (you should include t in the `meshgrid` call if you prefer to do 3D plots):

```matlab
t = 0;
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:.1:2,0:0.1:1);
u = dxdt(t,x,y);
v = dydt(t,x,y);
```

Now we should be able to plot:

```matlab
quiver(x,y,u,v);
```

---

For multiple `t` values, you can iterate and animate the plot:

```matlab
for t = linspace(0,4,100)
   u = dxdt(t,x,y);
   v = dydt(t,x,y);
   quiver(x,y,u,v);
   pause(0.5)
end
```

(Though unfortunately I don't see any changes with `t`?)

Comment: This worked great and created the exact image I was looking for, thank you so much for your help! I'm definitely still somewhat confused on the proper multiplication procedures but I'm sure with more practice I'll get a better grasp of it.

Comment: @BrittanyLazzaro You can use `.*` for every multiplication. I left `*` in where one of the two operands was a single value because there it doesn’t matter which one you use, and I’m lazy. But if in doubt, use `.*`. The `*` operator is matrix multiplication, which you only use if you’re doing linear algebra. See these docs for more information and examples: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should be aware of:

1. Please use element-wise operations, e.g., `.*` and `.^`, rather than matrix or vector operations, say, `*` and `^`;
2. Should unstack `d` into two individual partial derivatives, i.e., `dxdt` and `dydt`

## Code

```
f = @(t,x,y) (0.02.*sin(2.*pi.*t).*(x.^2 - 2.*x) + x);  
dfdx = @(t,x,y) (0.02.*sin(2.*pi.*t).*(2.*x - 2) + 1);
dxdt = @(t,x,y) -pi.*sin(pi.*f(t,x,y)).*cos(pi.*y); 
dydt = @(t,x,y) pi.*cos(pi.*f(t,x,y)).*sin(pi.*y).*dfdx(t,x,y);

[x,y] = meshgrid(0:.1:2,0:0.1:1);
t = linspace(0, 4, 100);
arrayfun(@(p) {figure;quiver(x,y,dxdt(p,x,y),dydt(p,x,y))}, t, UniformOutput=false);
```